# Can I install an air gap faucet instead of a basic air gap with my dishwasher?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

We are installing a new dishwasher and trying to figure out the air gap situation.  I know we need one, but I'd love to find a more functional alternative to a basic air gap.

I don't think we would really use a soap dispenser air gap and I've seen mixed reviews on them. I came across air gap faucets yesterday and am wondering if that would be compatible with a dishwasher instead of a reverse osmosis water system.

something like:
www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-Single-Handle-Water-Dispenser-Faucet-with-Air-Gap-and-Monitor-in-Chrome-for-Reverse-Osmosis-System-0958244/203208990

I think this should work in theory, but my only concern is the diameter of the hoses.  Apparently they are usually only 1/4" or 3/8" in diameter.  Is that too narrow for dishwasher waste water?

Answer (score 3):

The air gap in that faucet is specifically for a RO system and is not meant to replace an air gap for a dish washer.  It does the same job, but it's for the drain on the RO system, and certainly would not be able to handle anything close to a dishwasher drain.

[image]